Is this enough to grow muscle?
Full body workout 3 times (mon, wed, fri) a week with 3 sets x 8 reps all the time (only increasing weights)
-> Leg press, leg curl, leg extension, chest press, lat pulldown, shoulder press, seated row (all are machines)
My goal is to have lean muscle and look nice (not strength). Is this enough exercise?
